# Super-Scripting the Registration mark from XSLT code

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am making the registrration symbol super scripted through below  XSLT code

```
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#174;')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#174;')" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
        <![CDATA[&lt;sup&gt &#174; &lt;/sup&gt;]]>
        </xsl:text>
         <xsl:call-template name="SupersciptingRegistrationSymbol">
          <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,'&#174;')" />
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Now this XSL works correctly and replace the ® with <sup>®</sup> as i can verify it in the view source and in the debugging tools such as  Developer tool (chrome) and Firebug(Mozilla)tools.

**Now problem is that browser is rendering this text as it is (`<sup>®</sup>` ) rather than super-scripting it.**

Again whenever i edit `<sup>®</sup>` text in the firebug ® get super-scripted no matter what are the edit in that case.

NOTE- in page source it is looks  as below -

```
&lt;sup&gt &#174; &lt;/sup&gt;
```

What can be the issue here. Could someone help me to sort out this wired issue.

Comment: Have you actually tried `<![CDATA[<sup>®</sup>]]>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than messing around with `disable-output-escaping` using `xsl:text`, just include the `sup` element as a normal element:

```
  <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#174;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#174;')" />
    <sup>&#174;</sup>
    <xsl:call-template name="SupersciptingRegistrationSymbol">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#174;')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks a lot for your answer. Can you please provide me the reason for "not messing around with disable-output-escaping using xsl:text" here. your answer is perfect and resolved my issue.Please help me by providing the reason so that i can update my knowledge.

Comment: @user584 `disable-output-escaping` is a bit of a hack - processors are not necessarily required to support it at all, and even when they do it should be considered an option of last resort when there's no way to achieve what you want to do without it.  [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping) says this in so many words: "Since disabling output escaping may not work with all XSLT processors and can result in XML that is not well-formed, it should be used only when there is no alternative."

Comment: @user584 in particular, `disable-output-escaping` can only work when the XSLT processor itself is responsible for serializing the output tree to a stream.  It will always be ignored if the processor is sending its output directly to a DOM tree or another XML API such as a SAX `ContentHandler` (in the Java world).